# Find a several matches and export information from column B to same column in matching worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, match, copy-paste

I will try to explain this in the best possible way:

I have a ws called “Equipment List” that is overview of an inventory. I also have several ws called “Request lists 1”, “Request lists 2” and more.
The “Equipment List” includes a serial number for each item, but the “Request Lists” has all the information except for the serial.

I have a UserForm that calls up the available worksheets (“Request Lists”) and then I can choose the suitable.

I have also managed to create a DoubleClick “check” function in Column A “Equipment List”, based on this information I would like to:

1. When pressing a “Export” button I would like it to compare the information in column C,D,E and F in the “Equipment List” with the same columns in the “Request List” that I have chosen. (ListBox1.Value)
2. Then based on the “Check” in column A, copy the unique “Serial” (Column B) from “Equipment List” and paste it to the matching row and column found in in the “Request List”.
3. Then bring the “Location” from the “Request list” (H1) to the location column in “Equipment List”
   I have started working on the macro but have been unable to come up with anything useful.

Please understand my skills within VBA Is limited, but I am interested to learn more and i am very grateful if anyone could help me.

I have managed to make it so it copies the row based on information in col A Here is what i have so far:

```vb
Private Sub cbnExport_Click()

    For Each Cell In Sheets("Equipment List").Range("A4:A9999")
        If Cell.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
            matchRow = Cell.Row
            Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
            Selection.Copy
        
            Sheets(ListBox1.Value).Select
        
            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial 
    Paste:=xlPasteValues
                
            Sheets("Equipment List").Select
    
        End If
    Next

     Worksheets("Equipment List").Columns("A").ClearContents


    Sheets(ListBox1.Value).Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

[The process and what i am hoping to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fHVi.png)

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with your code? Do you need to find values using criteria in 4 columns instead of one?

Comment: The code I have works, but I would like to modify it to find matches in and populate the serial number from the equipment list to the request list. it need to match all columns (C,D,E,F) to ensure its identical. If it only matches with one of these it will most likely populate the row with wrong serial number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently looking at each row and checking one of its columns.

```vb
For Each Cell In Sheets("Equipment List").Range("A4:A9999")
    If Cell.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then     'checks value in column A only
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        ' do the rest    
    End If
Next
```

There are many ways to check other columns. Here is one way:

```vb
For Each Cell In Sheets("Equipment List").Range("A4:A9999")
    
    Dim ColA As String   ' place holders for Column A,B,C and D
    Dim ColB As String
    Dim ColC As String
    Dim ColD As String


   ' now, just fill in the values from current cell and the neighbors of it

   ColA = Cell.Value
   ColB = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value  'one cell to the right of column A is B
   ColC = Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value  'two cells to the right of A is C
   ColD = Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value  'three cells to the right of A is D

    If ColA = ChrW(&H2713) And ColB = "Criteria 9" And ColC = "22 1/2" And ColD = "22 1/2"  Then
        'we have matched all four columns
        matchRow = Cell.Row

        ' do other work here
        
    End If
Next
```

I hard coded the values for `ColB`, `ColC` and `ColD` in the `If-Then` block. You will need to replace them to be compared dynamically to what you are matching them against.

Comment: Thanks for your afford but i am afraid my knowledge is not quite on the level to complete the code based on your help. I would be very thankful if you could give it another try. Thanks